# Finding the maximum inscribed circle for given coordinates in Python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, geometry

In CMM dimensional measuring devices, there is an algorithm called the maximum inscribed circle, which can obtain the circle that will fit into this circle in the most appropriate way by taking the edge coordinates of the part.

http://www.cmmquarterly.mbccmm.com/index.php/training/general/236-calculations-for-circle-fitting-in-cmm-software

As someone who works on vision systems, I find the edge coordinates of the part. I also find the mean diameter using the circle-fitting library. But I could not write code to find the maximum inscribed circle parameters for this coordinate information. For example, the given coordinates are as follows:

```
coords = np.array([153,5348    122,1235]
                  [157,2310    256,3454]
                   .....................)
```

Can you help me with this?

Comment: if this were _image processing_ (pixels) instead of geometry (points), I'd say "distance transform". there *might* be _cheap_ geometry algorithms. I can only imagine something iterative (i.e. not that cheap).

Comment: Considering they only seem to use 16 points around the shape to fit the circle, finding the minimum inscribed circle brute-force is very doable. Just try all 560 combinations of 3 points. Easy. But this gets expensive fast as you increase the number of outline points. You’d have to use some heuristic to reduce the search space.

Comment: I'd start from _some_ center point (bounding box? bounding circle?), then iterate the distance to each point, pick the closest three, move it to be the center for those three, repeat until converged. I'm positive it'll converge. it feels convex.

Comment: I don't know how to decide inside/outside if given position of points only.

Comment: Please give the data.

Comment: This is called the *Chebyshev circle* - see <http://web.cvxr.com/cvx/examples/cvxbook/Ch04_cvx_opt_probs/html/chebyshev_center_2D.html>